# When we are at rest in our home, do we possess kinetic energy of earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, reference-frames

When we are stationary anywhere on earth, we say our kinetic energy is zero and we possess potential energy.

But when we see ourselves from space, we are rotating with earth, so we must possess kinetic energy of earth just like we are sitting in car, possessing car's kinetic energy.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

For all the good it does you, yes, you do "possess" a large kinetic energy given by your motion with the Earth about the solar system's reference frame.

However, there is no process that enables any changes to that kinetic energy, short of a collision with another planet or some other body with a mass that's at least not negligible with respect to the Earth's (which would be pretty catastrophic).

So: if you have something, but you cannot use it in any way, do you "possess it"? This is similar to the energy $E=mc^2$ that you "possess" from having a mass $m$: in principle, yes, it's there, but for all practical purposes it is inaccessible, so what's the use in considering it?

Comment: It would also be worth noting that kinetic energy is frame dependent, so comparing KEs from different frames is almost meaningless.

Comment: Does it mean energy is relative quantity which changes with respect to frame of reference? Bit confused how law of conservation of energy principle validates with the frame of reference?

Comment: @kumar Energy is a [torsor](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html)